# Open MediaElement in FullScreen

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, streaming, fullscreen, mediaelement

There is a MediaElement in my silverLight4 Application that plays videos.
There are also other controls in the form (listbox, buttons etc...).
When vieweing a Video, i want the option to switch to Fullscreen, but only the video and not all the form (something like youtube), is there a way to switch just the 'MediaElement' control to fullscreen?

Answer (score 0):

Make your `MediaElement` the `RootVisual` of the app.  Since you can't change the RootVisual once it's assigned you need to do something like so

```
private MainPage _mainPage = new MainPage();
private MediaElement _media = new MediaElement(); 

private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.Children.Add(_mainPage);
    this.RootVisual = grid;
}

public void FullscreenVideo()
{
    (this.RootVisual as Grid).Children.Clear();
    (this.RootVisual as Grid).Children.Add(_media);
    Application.Current.Host.Content.IsFullScreen = true;
}
```

If you call FullscreenVideo it should load your `MediaElement` into a fullscreen window

Comment: thanks, but not very clear, where to call FullscreenVideo() from? i can't seem to see it from another page.

Comment: When you switch the app to fullscreen now instead just change it to call `(Application.Current as App).FullscreenVideo();`

Comment: Thanks, but im receiving this error when i click on the fullscreen button (ELement is already the child of another element). Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to remove the MediaElement from it's current container before adding it to the `Application.RootVisual`.  To be honest with you I'm not sure what the best way to manage this will be.  You probably want to do something like passing the _media object to your MainPage and add that `MediaElement` to the MainPage in code.  Then before calling `FullscreenVideo()` you need to remove it from the container you added it to and then add it back after you exit fullscreen.